# Can you use "inert" as a synonym of "dead"?

Tags: meaning

I looked up the word "inert", and the definition does not match the definition for "dead", not even the slightest, yet dead is listed as a synonym. What do you think?

For example:

> The coffin of the inert man was ready.
>
> The wife was inert after she plunged off the building to her death.

Comment: **Inert** is a synonym for **dead** when **dead** is used metaphorically for machines rather than living things.  A car engine, for example, could be said to be either **dead** or **inert** when it is completely non-functional.

Comment: What about people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is dead, they are inert, but if someone is inert, they are not necessarily dead. So you can't use **inert** to mean **dead**.

The first sentence

> The coffin of the inert man was ready.

is never said like that, in fact it could imply that the man wasn't actually dead. It would more usually be something like

> The coffin for the deceased was ready.

The second sentence

> The wife was inert after she plunged off the building to her death.

is a tautology. It says "to her death" so the body can't be anything but inert.

Comment: can't it be used as an euphemism for dead?

Comment: Hm not usually. In the thesaurus I looked at **inert** was a "weak" synonym.